# How to locate element in script tag in selenium python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Here is the the html code:

```html
<html lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head></head>
  <body class="- view-form">
    <div id="container"> </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var sub_chart_path = "device";
      var is_dependency = false;
      var max_zoom_factor = 5;
      var image_name_base = "NHCTCC01";
    </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

What I want is to locate the element inside the `<script type="text/javascript">`. 
Can anybody tell me how it can be located?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: And what do you mean "Element inside the `script type = "text/javascript"`?

Comment: Selenium locates the web elements inside the web page. There are no web elements present inside the `<script type="text/javascript">`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `execute_script` with Javascript executor and get the variable in return

```
driver.execute_script("return sub_chart_path;")
```

> Should print:
>   device